Isosceles Triangle $AOB$ is Perpendicular to Plane $z=0$, $A$ and $B$ lie on known lines. $O$ is known. Find $A$ and $B$ coordinates
Suppose we have isosceles triangle $\Delta AOB$ $(AO = BO)$ lying on plane, that is perpendicular to the plane $z=0$ and coordinate of one point is known $O(x_0,y_0,z_0)$
Also there are two known lines, crossing at point $C(0,0,0)$: $AC$ and $BC$ (we do know their equations, but not coordinates of $A$ and $B$)
I think that this information is enough to find precise coordinates of $A(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, so I want to find them
What I've tried so far:

From perpendicularity of planes we know that their normal vectors are also perpendicular. Plane equation is
$$+(x-x_1)((y_2-y_1)*(z_0-z_1)-(y_0-y_1)*(z_2-z_1))\\
-(y-y_1)((x_2-x_1)*(z_0-z_1)-(x_0-x_1)*(z_2-z_1))\\
+(z-z_1)((x_2-x_1)*(y_0-y_1)-(x_0-x_1)*(y_2-y_1))\\ = 0$$
and $z$-coefficient of this plane must be equal to $0$, so
$$x_1y_2 + x_2y_0 + x_0y_1 - x_2y_1 - x_1y_0 - x_0y_2 = 0$$
Isosceles triangle gives one more equation of $(AO = BO)$
$$(x_0 - x_1)^2 + (y_0 - y_1)^2 + (z_0 - z_1)^2 = (x_0 - x_2)^2 + (y_0 - y_2)^2 + (z_0 - z_2)^2$$
or $$x_1^2-x_2^2+y_1^2-y_2^2+z_1^2-z_2^2-2x_0x_1+2x_0x_2-2y_0y_1+2y_0y_2-2z_0z_1+2z_0z_2=0$$
With six more parametric line equations (and plus two unknown parameters $t_1$,$t_2$) we have the following system of 8 equations with 8 unknown variables.
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_1y_2 + x_2y_0 + x_0y_1 - x_2y_1 - x_1y_0 - x_0y_2 = 0\\
x_1^2-x_2^2+y_1^2-y_2^2+z_1^2-z_2^2-2x_0x_1+2x_0x_2-2y_0y_1+2y_0y_2-2z_0z_1+2z_0z_2=0\\
x_1 = a_1t_1\\    
​y_1 = b_1t_1\\              
z_1 = c_1t_1\\    
x_2 = a_2t_2\\          
y_2 = b_2t_2\\
z_2 = c_2t_2
\end{array}
\right.$$
and this is where I got stuck
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(a_1b_2 - a_2b_1)t_1t_2 + (a_2y_0 - x_0b_2)t_2 + (x_0b_1 - a_1y_0)t_1 = 0\\
(a_1a_1 + b_1b_1 + c_1c_1)t_1^2 - (a_2a_2 + b_2b_2 + c_2c_2)t_2^2 - 2(a_1x_0+b_1y_0+c_1z_0)t_1 + 2(a_2x_0+b_2y_0+c_2z_0)t_2 = 0
\end{array}
\right.$$
All constants in brackets can be replaced with single-letter constants
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
t_1t_2 + qt_2 + wt_1 = 0\\
t_1^2 + dt_2^2 + ft_1 + gt_2 = 0
\end{array}
\right.$$
I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this system, or find any mistakes in my logic, or suggest easier approach.


Thanks in advance!

$a,b,c$ are known? Right? With those subscripts...

Yes, everything is known except coordinates of A(x1 y1 z1), B(x2 y2 z2) and parameters t1 t2

From $t_1t_2+qt_2+wt_1=0$, find $t_1$, which is:
$$t_1(w+t_2)=-qt_2$$
$$t_1=-\frac{qt_2}{w+t_2}$$
Put this value of $t_1$ in the second equation:
$$dt_2^2+\left(\frac{qt_2}{w+t_2}\right)^2+gt_2-f\left(\frac{qt_2}{w+t_2}\right)=0$$
$$d(w+t_2)^2t_2^2+q^2t_2^2+gt_2(w+t_2)^2-qft_2(w+t_2)=0$$
The rest is yours, seems to be quartic equation. I hope you can solve it.

I was so tired that missed such simple step, thank you!
